# No nginx rewriting HTTP to HTTPS, failing to redirect to docker containers

Tags: docker, http, nginx, reverse-proxy, cloudflare

I got a problem with nginx.
I use a reverse proxy to access some docker container, but if I use HTTP instead of HTTPS to access my domain, it will redirect to the default nginx page, and not redirect to my container.

Here's my nginx config for this boy.

```
server {
    server_name server.name1 server.name2;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:port hidden for safety; # some docker stuff
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.name1/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.name1/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}

server {
    if ($host = server.name2) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name server.name2;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Here some screenshots to explain

[webpage working properly if you type **manually** https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95K9H.png)

[webpage not working, redirecting to nginx default webpage **if you don't** precise https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDour.png)

I got the same problem with some of my configs. I'm kinda new to nginx and I'm using cerbot to generate certificates.
I tried to use another browser and empty cache / use icognito mode.

More, I use CloudFlare rather than OVH for DNS, and I check the "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites" was enabled, HSTS disabled.

I'm all open about suggestion for my network and how to proceed.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your server must also listen on port 443 which is for https. You might also need to setup the certs.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html
You can have it listening to both 80 and 443 as well.